# Syntax error in javascript: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm writing a little mozilla add-on, and I'm having the same issue on two classes.

```
var { ActionButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/action');

var MateButton = function(mate)
{
    var self = this;
    myMate: mate,
    button: ActionButton(
    {
        id: "my-button",
        label: self.myMate.message_OFF,
        icon:
        {
            "16": self.myMate.icon_OFF,
        }
    }),
    onChange: function()
    {
        var mate = self.myMate;
        var icon_tmp = ((mate.online == true) ? mate.icon_ON : mate.icon_OFF);
        var message_tmp = ((mate.online == true) ? mate.message_ON : mate.message_OFF);

        self.button.state("window",
        {
            "label": message_tmp,
            "icon":
             {
                "16": icon_tmp,
            }
        });
    }
};

exports.MateButton = MateButton;
```

**Issue :**

The console finds an error before "onChange: function()": SyntaxError:missing ; before statement.

I've tried to replace "," by ";" but the error becomes "function statement requires a name".

I've also tried to delete the function `onChange` and the colon before, but the error moved to the button definition.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Remove `,` here `"16": icon,`

Comment: `myMate: mate;` <<this shouldnt work either...replace `;` with `,`

Comment: Yes thank you, I changed "this.myMate = mate;" by "myMate: mate;" and forgot to change the ";". But it was already doing these errors before0

Comment: this is all mixed up.  You are half using function declarations and half using object declarations.

Comment: Yes, right. It's because i need some objects and one method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your declaring syntax mixed up here.  In part of your code you are using a Function Declaration, in another part you are using Object Declaration.

A Function Declaration involves running a section of code and returning **a single value**, whereas an Object Declaration ***runs no code***, and instead returns (implicity) **a series of key value pairs**, (`key: value`, separated by `,`).

Your `MateButton = function(mate)` line is stating that `MateButton` is a function, so the `key: value` pairs are out of place.  Try this:

```js
var MateButton = function(mate) {
  var self = this;
  self.myMate = mate;
  self.button = ActionButton({
    id: "my-button",
    label: self.myMate.message_OFF,
    icon: {
      "16": self.myMate.icon_OFF,
    }
  });
  self.onChange = function() {
    var mate = self.myMate;
    var icon_tmp = ((mate.online == true) ? mate.icon_ON : mate.icon_OFF);
    var message_tmp = ((mate.online == true) ? mate.message_ON : mate.message_OFF);

    self.button.state("window", {
      "label": message_tmp,
      "icon": {
        "16": icon_tmp,
      }
    });
  };
  return self;
};
```